# How to customize ShareAction layout for android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, shareactionprovider

How do i achieve something like this?

[image]

---

Android's default is like this ..
Any libraries for this? Please help

[image]

Comment: I was just looking at this yesterday, I noticed that the [open source](https://github.com/arpitkh96/AmazeFileManager) amaze file manager has a pretty nice share dialog. It might not be exactly what you described, but it is a starting point. To see what they have, install the app and tap and hold on an item then select *share*.

Comment: Thank you :) I will check it ..